# Wordpress Ajax Load More for two custom post types?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I need to pull two custom post types for a project I am working on in Wordpress. Right now I am using the Ajax load more plugin to easily use ajax. The problem is I want to add a class to the post types LI if they are *a type of post.*

For instance *my post types* are smiles and ads. So if it is a *smiles* post it should *add a smile class to the LI*. If it is an *ads* post it should add a *ad class to the LI*.  Please see the below code for reference.

Shortcode:

```
[ajax_load_more post_type="smiles, ads" posts_per_page="6" images_loaded="true" button_label="Load More"]
```

Repeater:

```
<?php if ($post->post_type == 'smiles') { ?>
        <li class=smile>
                <h3><?php the_author(); ?></h3>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class=x-fi><img src="<?php echo get_first_image(); ?>" /></a>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <?php echo getPostLikeLink( get_the_ID() ); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More / Comment...</a>
        </li>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($post->post_type == 'ads') { ?>
        <li class=ad>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Is this functionality able to be accomplished with the Ajax Load More plugin or is there an easier solution to accomplish this with AJAX / Jquery / PHP? As of right now the functionality with the plugin does not work as intended.

Comment: I'm not sur what you want to achieve? You want a load more button that make appear 6 more post?

Comment: I want one load more button that can pull two different post types and separate them with classes if it's possible.

Comment: Have you done a print_r of $post? if yes can we see it?

Comment: I've updated the content a bit. Seems people are getting a bit confused here. $post refers to wordpress's post query as I'm sure you are aware. At this point however I'd like to ask how I could accomplish this functionality with AJAX / JQUERY from scratch, the Ajax load more plugin seems to be a fluke for this.